# How to convert a softmax output to one-hot format in customized Keras loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

In a **2D semantic segmentation** task. I want to calculate an average dice coefficient for each category in a customized Keras loss function.

So I think **the first step** is calculate dice coefficients for each category, then **average** coefficients to get avg_dice.

Now my loss function looks like

```
def avg_dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, n_classes, smooth=1e-5):
    # y_pred_new = K.variable(np_utils.to_categorical(K.argmax(y_pred), num_classes=OPTIONS.nb_classes))

    avg_dice = 0.  # 用于求和每个类别的骰子系数，之后求平均
    for class_index in range(n_classes):  # 对每个类别进行循环
        intersection = K.sum(y_true[:, :, :, class_index] * y_pred_new[:, :, :, class_index], axis=[1, 2])
        union = K.sum(y_true[:, :, :, class_index], axis=[1, 2]) + K.sum(y_pred_new[:, :, :, class_index], axis=[1, 2])
        dice_one_class = K.mean((2. * intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth), axis=0)
        avg_dice += dice_one_class
    return avg_dice / n_classes  # 之后求平均
```

in this function, y_pred is **outputs from network after softmax**, labels_shape=(batch_size, 1024, 512, n_classes), predicts_shape=(batch_size, 1024, 512, n_classes)

I think my loss is wrong because I use float y_pred. According to the equation

[image]

I think I should use integer 0 or 1 y_pred  value instead of float. So I need to 1) use K.argmax() to get the index of max value of each pixel, 2) convert the result of K.argmax() to one-hot format.(A simple example: convert [0.1, 0.1, 0.8] to [0, 0, 1])

But when I add

```
y_pred_new = K.variable(np_utils.to_categorical(K.argmax(y_pred), num_classes=OPTIONS.nb_classes))
```

to achieve this goal, I got an error:

**ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**

How can I repair my loss and **whether my idea of averaging is right?**

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the function `np_utils.to_categorical()` needs `array` but it got a `sequence` likes a `tensor`.

I met the problem too, then I changed `np_utils.to_categorical()` into `tf.one_hot`, it works.

Hope this helps:D